# Arrays of pointer to matrices initialized with arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I want to cycle between different matrices using an array of pointer to matrices.I want those matrices' rows initialized using array variables. For different reasons, I can't create a new class.

More specifically I want somethng like that:

First point

```
#define SIZE size-value
int row1MatrixM [SIZE]= {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
int row2MatrixM [SIZE] = {2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12};
...
```

Then:

```
matrixM= {row1MatrixM, row2MatrixM, row3MatrixM .... };
```

But the complier says I can't initialize a matrix this way.

Now I have:

```
matrixM, matrixY, matrixX, matrixZ, etc.
```

Then I would like to access them using pointers, so I would need an array of pointers (a pointer to M, one to Y, etc.)

So I tried to write something like that:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_MATRICES number-of-matrices-value
int[SIZE][SIZE]* arrayOfPointersToMatrices[NUMBER_OF_MATRICES] = {&matrixM,&matrixY,&matrixX, &matrixZ};
```

I tried different combinations of [] and ** but no one seems working. I was looking for a type that would allow me to access to the array of pointers (3D array) with brackets:

```
arrayOfPointersToMatrices[x][y][z]
```

Comment: *But the complier says I can't initialize a matrix this way.* [Are you sure?](https://ideone.com/bdmURQ)

Comment: "cannot initialize an array element of type int with an lvalue of type int[16]" (sic)

Comment: Did you see the code I linked? It compiled just fine for me...perhaps you're declaring it of the wrong type?

Comment: It seems it worked. So I suppose for the matrix part it should be int** arrayOfMatrices[NumberOfMatrices] ? I will try that, too

Comment: Beware; with that declaration you're entering [Three Star](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) territory...

Comment: Yeah I would not do it  but I have to. However the array of matrices says "cannot initialize an array element of 'type int**' with an lvalue of type 'int[16][16]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To get your code working:

Declare the arrays like:

```
int row1 [NUM_COLS]= {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
int row2 [NUM_COLS] = {2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

Declare the 2d matrices like:

```
int *matrix2d1[NUM_ROWS] = {row1, row2};
int *matrix2d2[NUM_ROWS] = {row3, row4};
```

Declare the 3d matrices like:

```
int **matrix3d[NUM_MATRICES] = {matrix2d1, matrix2d2};
```

## An alternative (the "right" way)

I would highly highly *highly* suggest using vectors. They're baked into the C++ language and infinitely easier than all this array/pointer work.

Comment: Yes, std library and other data structures are way better than "my" solution. I would never use pointers to pointers to ... neither but for different reasons, I am forced to.

Comment: @EagleOne I figured as much, which is why I wrote the first part for you. The second is for anyone in the future coming to this question with the same problem but different limitations.

Comment: Yes and in closing, I was forced to ask exactly because I never used such "data structures"